# Connecting to oracle DB through C

Tags: c, oracle

I want to connect to oracle database using C language in Windows OS. But I do not how to start with it and what will be pre-requisite?
 can any one provide me any help or tutotial or sample code?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at OCILIB (http://orclib.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: I looked..it will help..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/30799-how-to-connect-c-with-oracle/

Oracle C++ Call Interface (OCCI) is an Application Programming Interface (API) that provides C++ applications access to data in an Oracle database.

To know more about the OCCI refer here

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/oci/index-090820.html