# how can C communicate with Oracle database?

Tags: c, oracle

Newbie question here: I'm using ANSI C on server to crunch numbers for a web application. The C function needs to load data from an Oracle database, process it, and save it back to the database.

Is C capable of doing this, or do I need another language as a middle-man?

How do people approach this problem?

Do I need to build a bridge from C to another language, for example, learn JNI or build a PHP extension, and let them do the communicating with the database? I'm trying to avoid this route because it's seems fairly complex. Hoping to converge on a simple approach. That is, a (mainstream) approach that is well documented with examples on the internet, or if I need to ask a question there's lots of people around that have done it.

Comment: Why tagged with [tag:jdbc]? I thought the whole point of JDBC is the **J**, Java. But you want to work in C. So... why the [tag:jdbc]?

Comment: I though there was a connection between JDBC and OCI. From http://www.vipan.com/htdocs/javadatabase.html it states: `JDBC can use four types of drivers to connect to the databases... Type 2 driver translates its calls to the native (C, C++ etc.) API calls of the wanted database (e.g. Oracle Call Interface calls) which then call the wanted database. You will need a driver for each database and operating system combination. This is usually the case. Performance is faster than Type 4 drivers.`

Comment: Sure, but if you're writing C, then you doubtless want the C interfaces, right?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7382984/790070)

Comment: unixODBC might be another solution, not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use Oracle [OCI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/oci/index.html), which is a bunch of C APIs to interface with the database.

Comment: It should be noted that OCI is not JDBC (because it was mentioned in the post).

Answer (score 2):

IF you are licensed for Oracle,  a simpler C interface to Oracle than OCI is available.  It is on your distribution disk.  Pro*C.

There is nothing wrong with OCI at all, it simply can require several calls to do what one call in Pro*C accomplishes.  In either event, OCI or Pro*C, you have some serious reading to do.  Hopefully you already know some Oracle SQL  so that doesn't become yet another hurdle for you.

I code in both, but use OCI for interfacing C to Oracle in external library modules (external C calls that perform special functions, and OCI is required for this.).  Pro*C is for production application code, including some high performance number crunching.

Comment: How does Pro*C compare with OCILIB and/or OCCI? I *think* all of these  are intended to simply coding.

Comment: Pro*C "replaced" OCI, about version 4 of Oracle. When you are using tools sensibly, you assign tasks to tools that handle the task the best. For example, asking Oracle, say PL/SQL, to do lots of number crunching is not as efficient as crunching in C. And then updating, inserting, etc. into oracle using Pro*C. OCI and Pro*C are interfaces to Oracle functionality. You choose the tool and functionality you want. What OCI accomplishes is closely comparable to what Pro*C does - ask Oracle to do something and maybe give you the result.